# How to filter a JavaScript object in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to show a list of user uids and some information about them, except for the information of a specific user.

Here is an example of my JavaScript object, which I am storing in as a `usersData` state:

```js
{
  "alkfklnj2340": {
    "uid": "alkfklnj2340",
    "username": "username1"
  },
  "235o2hifoiid": {
    "uid": "235o2hifoiid",
    "username": "username2"
  }
}
```

For example, I want to return a new object without `alkfklnj2340`, so:

```js
{
  "235o2hifoiid": {
    "uid": "235o2hifoiid",
    "username": "username2"
  }
}
```

I have tred this so far, which doesn't quite output what is expected:

```js
const filteredUsers = Object.keys(this.state.usersData).filter((key, i) =>
    this.state.usersData[key].uid != this.state.userUid
);
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to output and what value are you getting? What is userUid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `for...in` loop

```
let result = {};
for (const key in this.state.usersData) {
    if (key !== this.state.userUid) {
        result[key] = this.state.usersData[key];
    }
}
```

or a `forEach` loop:

```
let result = {};
Object.keys(this.state.usersData).forEach(key => {
  if (key !== this.state.userUid) {
    result[key] = this.state.usersData[key];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to construct a new dictionary.

```js
var filteredUsers = Object.keys(this.state.usersData).reduce((filteredUsers, key) => {
    if (this.state.usersData[key].uid != this.state.userUid) {
        filteredUsers[key] = this.state.usersData[key];
    }
    return filteredUsers;
}, {});
```

This will start from a new dictionary `{}` and keep setting key+value when the condition is met.

You can also do it like this:

```js
var filteredUsers = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(this.state.usersData).filter(([key,value]) => this.state.usersData[key].uid != this.state.userUid));
```

`Object.entries()` turns dictionary into an entry list.
`Object.fromEntries()` turns an entry list back to a dictionary.